# Angular modules for admin/user scenario

Tags: angular, module, architecture, angular-module, ng-modules

I'm designing an Angular application which has admin and basic user view of every major feature.

Let's say I have two features - **Users** and **Products**, where each `User` can have none or many `Products`.

Each `User` can create, view and manage their own profile and connected `Products`.
Admin can create, view and manage all `Users` and all `Products`, as well as `Products` for each `User`.

I'd like to avoid loading admin-specific stuff for basic users and vice-versa. I guess lazy-loading is the key. My question is do I create one module for each feature and divide *basic*, *admin* and *shared* stuff inside, or should I make *basic*, *admin* and *shared* my main modules, and divide from there?

Or is there a better approach I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular guards to restrict normal user to access your Admin module. In my opinion you should have separate modules for Admin, User, Products and Shared to share common resources across. In this way you can keep the modules separated and even implement lazy loading specific to each module as well.